# Color of curves and their control elements, question 2

Tags: color, bezier-curves

When I draw Bezier curves, they get initially displayed as thin black lines or curves, which can't be seen well against a dark background.

Then, later, they are displayed as thin yellow or orange lines or curves.

Where can these two colors be changed? Where can their thickness be changed?

Also, can I change the size. length, or color of vertices and control points and lines?

I'm not sure if I need this for object mode, edit mode, 2d, or 3d, sorry. I just want to change these in general, at least for now. In case it isn't obvious, I'm a beginner.

(There is a question with duplicate title that seems to discuss something not quite the same. I don't understand the answers to that question, but I cannot create comments there.)

Yes, I have tried finding this in the Manual but haven't read all of it. I have also searched the Web before posting this question. I'm posting this out of the hope that there is an expert out there who might want to help a beginner.

Comment: You can change just about everything about the 3D window in the User Preferences. At top left, select "File-->User Preferences".  Need more help?  Leave a comment and I'll point you to it. Unable to at the moment.

Comment: I have of course looked at the nodes in Menu > File > User Preferences..., but just like the Manual, it is very large and complicated. Can someone expert please take a minute to describe in detail the answers to my original question? The advanced features of Blender are easy to use, but the converse is not true. The elementary features, like those of standard drawing programs, mostly seem implemented in totally nonintuitive ways. Just my opinion, of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the bezier curve thickness, but for the rest of the changes take a look below.

Go to user preferences (shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + U).Go to themes on the top and 3d view on the side.
[image]

Among these options,(10th row from top), 'vertex select' and 'vertex' will change the vertex colors for selected and non-selected vertices respectively.(both for bezier curves and mesh objects)

[image]

And in the 24th row, 'align handle selected' will change the handle colors of bezier curves in edit mode. Other settings for bezier curves, start with 'NURBS'

[image]

Scroll down until you see something like this.

[image]

'Vertex size' is for the size of bezier vertices and the usual mesh object vertices.

Comment: I experimented: the curve color is controlled by "wire edit". Thanks for the great starting point. Trust me, it wasn't obvious to a beginner.

Comment: I know :) Even I came to know about these settings after several years of using blender. You did the right thing by asking here..